# How to Check in and Check Out Power Builder Code

Tags: powerbuilder

How to Check in and Check Out Power Builder Code.

I generally see they will do by exporting and checking in the code. But i am getting some dependency error when i am trying to import objects one by one.

Could someone please help me how to do this entire process of checking in and out of power builder code.
Do we have to use any other third party software for this purpose?

Comment: You should at least tell what version of PB you use and what SCM. Or maybe you just try to use "PBNative"? Also post an example of error message you got. As is we are missing information to help.

Comment: I am using PB 11.5 and
SVN

Comment: And what scc<->svn adapter do yo use?

Answer (score 3):

In your comments above you say you're using PB 11.5 and SVN.

I'm the author of the [Agent SVN](http://www.zeusedit.com/agent/pb/classic.html) plug-in and it integrates PowerBuilder with Subversion.

It does this using the MS-SCCI interface, meaning you integrate with SVN using the source control menus found inside PowerBuilder itself.

Because it uses MS-SCCI that means PowerBuilder itself will decide what needs to be done when-ever objects are checked in or out.

**NOTE:** Agent SVN is shareware.

Answer (score 0):

When adding objects to source control you need to bring in the base classes (ancestors) first.  Once these are successfully brought into the .pbl/target you can then add any descendant classes.